# How do you disable Smart Invert or truly invert all of your screen colors?

Tags: macos, display, mojave, color, accessibility

In previous macOS, when you used the **Invert Colors** feature (*Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Invert Colors*), all the colors on the screen would become inverted, including images, so a page [like this one](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_l%27oie_(jeu_de_soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9)) would look like this:

[image]

<sub>*Note the image has blue tones and the rolling dice is black at the top*</sub>

In recent macOS (I use **Mojave**), a feature called "**Smart Invert**" makes it now impossible to invert images on a webpage. 
The same page would now look like this:

[image]

<sub>*Note how the dice and the image on the right have "normal" colors - and not the top left logo for some mysterious reason*</sub>

How does one disable the so-called "Smart" part of the invert? 
It simply doesn't work for anyone trying to invert images, which a lot of people deal with very often, whether in [the art world](http://myartguides.com/exhibitions/wael-shawky-al-araba-al-madfuna/attachment/schermata-2016-10-19-alle-09-50-07/), [historical research](http://www.vam.ac.uk/content/journals/conservation-journal/spring-2012-issue-60/positive-negative/) or any other photography-related fields. Besides, "Dark Mode" already does that.

### **How do I quickly invert images on my display?**

Comment: I'm wondering this too, I'm sure it's just a plist option or something, it's frustrating no one else seems to have found a fix.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the issue you were facing - it seems to happen on Safari. Have you thought about trying Firefox? It seems to not "Smart invert" on Firefox from what I can tell.

(I can't add a comment due to reputation).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).   - From Review